# Installing packages of R in UBUNTU

Tags: server, package-management, r

i have an  R script that looks like this:

```
install.packages("R.utils")
library("R.utils")
install.packages("vcfR")
library("vcfR")
install.packages("stringr")
library("stringr")
install.packages("tidyverse")
library("tidyverse")
install.packages("dplyr")
library("dplyr")
gunzip("gnomad.exomes.r2.1.1.sites.21.vcf.bgz", "gnomad.exomes.r2.1.1.sites.21.vcf")
vc=read.vcfR("gnomad.exomes.r2.1.1.sites.21.vcf")
df=vc@fix
data=as.data.frame(df)
data_snp=data %>%
  filter(str_length(ALT)==1 & str_length(REF)==1)#filtering for SNPs
data_snp$snp_id <- str_c("chr21","-", data_snp$POS)
data_snp$AF_total=str_extract(data_snp$INFO, "(?<=AF=)[^;]+")
data_snp$AF_latin=str_extract(data_snp$INFO, "(?<=AF_amr=)[^;]+")
data_snp$INFO=NULL
data_snp$key=str_c(data_snp$snp_id,"-",data_snp$ALT,"-",data_snp$REF)
df_for_filter=read.csv("merged_df.csv")
df_x=subset(df_for_filter,df_for_filter$CHROM=="chr21")
df_x$snp_id=str_c("chr21","-",df_x$POS)
df_x$key=str_c(df_x$snp_id,"-",df_x$ALT,"-",df_x$REF)
filter_df=data_snp %>% semi_join(df_x, by = "key")
results=read.csv("result_armitage_test.csv")
results$chrom=substr(results$snp_id,1,5)
results_y=subset(results,results$chrom=="chr21")
resuts_21=merge(x = results_y, y =filter_df, by = "snp_id", all.x = TRUE)
resuts_21$CHROM=NULL
resuts_21$POS=NULL
resuts_21$CHROM=NULL
resuts_21$FILTER=NULL
resuts_y$QUAL=NULL
resuts_21$key=NULL
write.csv(resuts_21,"result_chr21.csv")
```

i run this script in UBUNTU :

```
xxxxx@xxxx:~% Rscrips chr_21.R
```

but it returns an error :

```
CORRECT>Rscript chr_21.R (y|n|e|a)? yes
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("R.utils") :
  'lib = "/usr/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("R.utils") : unable to install packages
Execution halted
```

I cant understand what is wrong why the library cant be installed and how to fix this .thank you:)

Comment: what are the permissions on `/usr/lib/R/site-library`?

Comment: @Esther how do i check the premissions? sorry im new to UBUNTU

Comment: `ls -ld /usr/lib/R/site-library` will do it

Comment: @Esther drwxr-xr-x 122 root root 2941 Mar  2  2021 /usr/lib/R/site-library/

Comment: In general you will need admin rights to install anything in the system folders like `/usr/lib/R/site-library/`.

Comment: @Esther so  there is nothing i can do ?

Comment: You would need `sudo` to install stuff in that folder, since it is owned by `root` and only writable by `root`. This is assuming you actually want the libs to be installed there, and not somewhere else.

Comment: @Esther how can i use sudo , wht are the steps , again sorry im new to unix and the whole environment

Comment: @user68186 should  i enter the command in the UBUNTU terminal?

Comment: @user68186 adduser: Command not found. - returns , im using my university cluster maybe it doesnt work on it?

Comment: @user68186 how do i check the version?

Comment: @user68186 is it OK in terms of privecy to use the sudo usermod -a -G staff command on univerity cluster?

Comment: @user68186 No LSB modules are available.

Comment: That is fine. This command should give you the Ubuntu version in any case. I don't understand why you get command not found for `adduser`.

Comment: If you are working on a university cluster, you will likely need to ask the system's administrators to install the packages for you - or else configure R to use a local (user) library location (perhaps by creating a `~/.Renviron` file specifying an `R_LIBS_USER` path?)

Comment: @user68186 likely `adduser` is not found because `/usr/sbin` is not in their `PATH` (since they are an unprivileged user)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the clarification. I didn't think of the possibility of in school use. Your explanation and the answer below makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working on a university cluster, you will likely need to ask the system's administrators to install the packages site-wide - or else configure R to install packages to a local (user) library location.

If you haven't already set up a local library, then the easiest way seems to be to execute `R` interactively, attempt to install a package, and follow the instructions when site-wide installation fails.

First, start `R` and check the current library search path:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

OK now let's try to install the `stringr` package:

```
> install.packages("stringr")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("stringr") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
```

(it fails, then prompts)

```
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel) yes
Would you like to create a personal library
‘/home/steeldriver/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’ to install packages into? (yes/No/cancel) yes
also installing the dependencies ‘glue’, ‘magrittr’, ‘stringi’
```

(after some time)

```
* DONE (stringr)

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpsVbbe1/downloaded_packages’
>
```

Now you can check that the newly-created libPath has been added:

```
> 
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/steeldriver/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                            
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

FWIW the default user library location seems to come from a template in the /etc/R/ environment files:

```
$ grep R_LIBS_USER /etc/R/*
/etc/R/Renviron:R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER:-'%U'}
/etc/R/Renviron.site:#R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/@R_PLATFORM@-library/@MAJ_MIN_VERSION@'}
```

Once you've done that for *one* package, your script should run and install the rest to your new user library.